# Data management with an Excel Access interface

Tags: xml, excel, ms-access, ddl, dml

What would be the best approach on building a data management system using both excel and access?

I'm working with enough data to make it impossible to handle it alone with excel, still, I need the reporting power of it.

I'm thinking... the best approach would be to build my data structure (ddl) with xml, to use access so users could manipulate the data (dml), query it back to xml, export the xml queries to be run by excel reporting scripts.

Am I making sense? I'm driving my learning process towards that goal. Is it a reasonable solution, or there are better solutions for interfacing access with excel?

Answer (score 0):

Can't tell from your approach summary whether that's a sensible way to go or not, but Access does have a UI for directly developing schemas/entities/queries, and Excel has the ability to connect directly to an Access DB to bring in data to a spreadsheet from Access tables and queries -- all with the designed UI and connectivity features of the two products, not via XML manipulations. It depends greatly on what your full solution is and who your target users are. I've made fairly complex Access databases that dynamically create SQL via VB code, but end users access the data in an Excel spreadsheet via a click-to-create Connection to Access that pulls data from the Access queries and puts it in tables for easy analysis with pivot tables. That kind of solution uses many of the built-in capabilities of Access and Excel. If you're bound to Access and Excel as your tools, using the innate strengths of the two seems like it might be easier than going an XML-based route that sounds portable but not geared to Access/Excel unique capabilities.

Comment: Ricardo, after reading your response, I'll add a couple of comments.  - As you found with Excel forms, you might not like the proprietary capabilities of Access and/or Excel. They might not be a good match for your skillset, might not be worth learning, etc. - Access SQL has more quirks than other RDBMSs, and though it's a plus that it is file-based rather than server-based, it's a minus that its SQL is odd and missing some useful syntax options

Comment: Clarifying: Access being file-based _may_ provide a plus in infrastructure simplicity and ease-of-use. There are many reasons why file-based DBs are not a plus, but I'm guessing you're using Access because you already have it and it's easy to get started and use . . .

Comment: Yes, I'm bound to excel/access solutions mainly due to in work constraints. Actually, I think my biggest problem now is evolving from self oriented programming, to suit my own work related needs, to programming a multi-user sensible environment. And, although I absolutely recognize excel/access power (ranging far beyond the solutions I'm trying to build) I feel that, most of the times, I have to reinvent a new wheel, and that there's too much noise behind programming it.

Comment: What would it be a good alternative? Good match for my skillset (worth learning)?

Comment: Well, Excel/Access has shortcomings as a multi-user environment that a server-based RDBMS (MySQL, Postgres, SQL Server, Oracle, etc.) and a modern web-based UI (HTML 5, node.js, etc.) doesn't have, and those skills are clearly more valuable in the software development world than Access. But there are so many alternatives that it doesn't mean much to suggest one. Access, particularly its dev UI and VB-based development, definitely qualifies as a legacy technology in my mind, and on its way out over time. </opinion>.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the thing is... I'm still navigating thru data access objects, so your feedback, RealHandy, is much appreciated, thanks. The fact is, for now I developed a bit with excel VBA, and the solution I found to handle immense data (say, a table with approximately a million rows) was to break the data into smaller versions of xml files (so I could import them sparsely, whenever needed).

I know access handles this faster, yes, but I guess it lacks the flexibility to, given a random .xls or .txt file, automate the process of capturing the information I need from the reports I receive. Then, the information being route like that, in .xml, has also the advantage of being a safe backup, I guess.

Now I'm striving with the need to create a dbms, preferably being the most user-friendly possible, so it can capture a lot of other variables from a lot of other possible users. First, I tried a bit with userforms in excel and I dimmed it unfit for the task, after all, if I need access to process data, access should also handle better with forms.

That said, I'm focusing on getting the best relational model from the data I'd like to gather (it's complex) and I'll model it first by using access's engine but, for a lack of a better word, having the raw data modeled as an xml structure as a better appeal to me.

Answer (score 0):

First, consider a closer look at the objects you specified. Then, you can see MS Access is more than just a user interface and Excel more than a reporting tool.

MS Access is a database management system (not itself a [database](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33216/ms-access-or-mdb-or-access-database-engine-or-ms-jet-ace)) that comes equipped with a suite of objects:

1. [Jet/ACE Engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Jet_Database_Engine) with SQL dialect query processor *(a Windows .dll technology that all PC users have regardless of Access installation)*
2. Form user interface toolkit *(trigger events, command buttons, data management GUI for users)*
3. Report generator *(exportable to PDF, HTML, XML, Excel)*
4. Flat file import/export facilities *(to handle txt, csv, xml, xlsx files)*
5. VBA coding environment *(can use the object of model of any of its Office siblings directly including MS Excel, Outlook, Word, Powerpoint)*
6. ODBC/OLEDB facilities *(capable of directly connecting to server level RDMS as backends: Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, etc.)*

MS Excel is a spreadsheet manipulator, typically an end-use product, with a variety of functionality:

1. Data handling with formula and string/math function building
2. Statistical and graphical analysis
3. Pivot table/chart reporting
4. Flat file import/export features including documents and PDF output
5. VBA coding environment for macros and modules *(can also use any of sibling Office products' object models)*
6. ODBC/OLEDB connections with [Business Intelligent (BI) tools](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Business-intelligence-in-Excel-and-Excel-Services-SharePoint-Server-2013-2740f10c-579d-4b40-a1d9-7beb5d38547c#__toc381114615) including Power Pivot and OLAP

XML is not a software but fundamentally a data type using nested tree structure which are not governed to the two-dimensions of rows and columns, typical of most data pieces. Interestingly, Excel spreadsheets starting in [Office 2007](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338205%28v=office.12%29.aspx) are actually a collection of underlying xml formatted files.

With that said, see all three as part of a complimentary ecosystem. MS Access can serve as the central repository to house (DDL) and manage (DML) your large volume of data using a relational SQL engine. And by users' demands, Access can export real-time data to xml, xlsx, or pdf for final, end use needs. Then, with Word, Adobe, Excel, or web apps, users can furnish their customized solutions.

Comment: Parfait, too my knowledge an xml tree strucure is always capable of beeing two dimensionally translated... Nested two dimensional data structures.

Comment: I'm not trying to diminish excel or access power by saying I need the reporting power of one, or the data manipulation usability of the other. I'm saying I'm trying to get the best from both environments.

Comment: And I hope I communicated that you can use all three together: a secured, relational database; a spreadsheet analyzer; XML input/outputs. And yes as an open-ended structured data type, XML can be two-dimensional and with XSLT complex XML can be transformed for database migration!